# For each username, how do I create a user account using the Linux useradd command off reading a CSV file

Tags: ruby

I need to also ensure that the First and Last Names form part of the account information for each user. For example if the user's name is Allen Truth, I need to print Truthan and " The account for Allen Truth." Then generate passwords for each user-created.

```
employeeData = CSV.parse(File.read("employeedata.csv"), headers: true
  User.find_or_create_by(name: row[:first_last]) do |user|  
    user.username = row[:username]  
    user.name = row[:first_last]  
  end  
end
```

This is what I have, not exactly sure where to go from here to get the script to operate properly.

Comment: Where is `row` being defined?

Comment: rows = CSV.read("path/to/employeedata.csv")

Comment: Sorry I didn't place that in the code.